# How to drag image or text in exiting PDF using syncfusion library in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, pdf, itext

I am new to Flutter. In my current application, I want to add images and text to existing pdf
to any x, y location and save that pdf again.

To view the pdf currently, I am using the below code.

```
SfPdfViewerTheme(
  data: SfPdfViewerThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        SfPdfViewer.memory(
        widget.fileData,
        controller: _pdfViewerController,
        canShowPasswordDialog: true,
        canShowScrollStatus: true,
        scrollDirection: PdfScrollDirection.vertical,
        interactionMode: PdfInteractionMode.selection,
        pageLayoutMode: PdfPageLayoutMode.continuous,
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Basically, I am using the "syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer" library to view the pdf.

Any idea how to add an image or text to any X,Y location on PDF using the "syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer" library?

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart'; I am using this package. Is it comes under the license?

Comment: Yes, that is a syncfusion package, and is subject to the commercial license.

Comment: Is there any way to use its  Free Syncfusion Community license? Or Have you used any license?

Comment: The free community license is very limited.  You must apply for it, you must have fewer than five collaborators, and even if you publish it on github, EVERY consumer of your code has to independently apply for the free community license.  It's very restricted.